# Execute bash on logon and add alias

Tags: linux, alias, bash

When I login to a Linux server per Putty, I want to execute the `bash` (because the default shell is another) and after that adding an alias.

I tried several combinations of putting `exec bash` in the `.profile` and adding `alias foo='echo foo'` into `.bash_profile`. But I didn't find out the correct combination. Either the alias wasn't set, or the bash wasn't executed.

So, the question is, in which of these files:

```
.profile
.bashrc
.bash_profile
```

do I have to put these commands:

```
exec bash
alias foo='echo foo'
```

to run the `bash` shell and have access to my alias every time I login to the server?

**edit**: We're using all the same user to login. But I want to execute the bash and adding the alias only for my remote machine. I do already have a suitable `if` statement for that. I only have to know, where to put these commands!

**edit2**:

What I have so far in my `.profile`:

```
if [ $(who -m | awk '{print $NF}' | grep "myHostName" | wc -l) -eq 1 ]
then
    exec bash
    alias foo='echo foo'
fi
```

This will execute the bash for only *my* user. But the alias will be ignored, since I'm starting a new shell and the alias will be probably set in the old shell...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, finally I figured it out by myself with the great help of **BroSlow**.

I wrote the following to my `.profile`:

```
if [ $(who -m | awk '{print $NF}' | grep "myHostName" | wc -l) -eq 1 ]
then
  exec bash
fi
```

and the other part to the `.bash_profile`:

```
if [ $(who -m | awk '{print $NF}' | grep "myHostName" | wc -l) -eq 1 ]
then
  alias foo='echo foo'
fi
```

This solved my problem!

On logon, the `.profile` will be sourced automatically and will execute the bash.
After that the `.bash_profile` will be sourced due to the fact, that the `bash` shell will source it's **own** profile.

However: thanks a lot for the support!

Comment: `if who -m | awk '{print $NF}' | grep -q "myHostName"; then` will check if there was any match, instead of needing to count lines and compare the result to 1.

Answer (score 3):

Going to go out on a limb and guess you want to do this because your default shell isn't bash. Don't. Just change your default shell

```
> chsh -s /bin/bash
```

Then put

```
alias foo='echo foo'
```

In either `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`

If multiple users are using the same account, you can try to do the following. While logged in, run

```
> who -a | grep $(ps -p $PPID -o ppid=) | awk '{print $NF}'
```

This may be system dependent, but on a couple I tried it on, this will get location you're logged in from. Once you have that output, do the following

```
if [[ $(who -a | grep $(ps -p $PPID -o ppid=) | awk '{print $NF}') == output ]]; then 
  alias foo='echo foo'
done
```

If you're ssh-ing from multiple computers, then I don't think there is any way to do what you want. Simplest would be to make your own file in the home directory, and then source it manually each time you log in.

e.g.

```
> touch myfile.txt
> echo "alias foo='echo foo'" >> myfile.txt
> source myfile.txt
> foo
foo
```

So you would just have to run `source myfile.txt` each time you log in or just have putty source it by default.

Comment: Would it also be possible doing `chsh -s /bin/bash` in a profile file, so I can execute it only on specific conditions (like remote host is `myHost`)? Because I'm running on a server where I'm not the only one and I don't want to change other users behavior!

Comment: @bobel Every user gets his own default shell (info stored in `/etc/passwd/`), that won't change it for anyone else.

Comment: Okay, sorry, I didn't explain myself very well... We're all using the same user to login on this server :)

Comment: Thanks for your edit! This is how I'm already doing it. But how and where can I execute my bash in exact this way?

Comment: @bobbel See update, might be a simpler way to do this, but not one I can think of off hand

Comment: Indeed, I can source a file "if login remote host is mine". This would work! But I didn't find a way to let execute the bash in this way **and** add an alias after. This is probably a vicious circle, isn't it?

Comment: @bobbel You would put whatever aliases/functions/variables in the file to source. And makes no difference if host `is yours`. Whatever you source manually is isolated to your particular shell instance.

Answer (score 0):

To set up alias in startup change your .bash_profile
Add alias to bash profile:

```
$ cd
$ sudo nano .bash_profile
$ alias ALIAS_NAME='COMMAND'
```

Update bash profile

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```